# Can't pass this through prototyped function

Tags: javascript, module

I have the following module and submodule:

```
// Parent module "API"
var API = function(){
    console.log('loading API');
    this.param = 12345;
}

// A method for instantiating the City module via the API
API.prototype.City = function(){
    return City(this);            // <--- Can't pass this here? 
}

// Submodule "City"
var City = function(api){
    console.log("loading City");
    console.log(api);            // <--- Just prints empty object {}
}

var api = new API();
console.log(api);
var denver = new api.City();
```

I would expect to be able to pass the `api` object into the `City` object by passing `this` when instantiating it. But it just passes an empty object.

Final output:

```
loading API
{ config: 12345 }
loading City
{}
```

Is it not possible to pass the parent module into a submodule when instantiating it?

Comment: What exactly do you intend by using the `new` keyword in `new api.City()`?  That's going to invoke the function with a newly-created object as the value of `this`.

Comment: Works swimmingly for me, the `api` parameter shows in the console as `API.City`, which is what it should be

Comment: @adeneo can you put up a fiddle that shows it working?

Comment: That makes sense @Pointy I hadn't considered that...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rqu7n7t4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
API.prototype.City = function(){
    return new City(this);
//         ^^^
}
```

and

```
…
var denver = api.City();
//              ^^^^^^^ standard *method* call
```